# Multi-volume work with unnumbered volume in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

In biblatex, the field `volumes` can be used to indicate the number of volumes in a multi-volume work. But how can I indicate that a multi-volume work has e.g. 8 numbered volumes plus a supplementary unnumbered volume, e.g. an index?

Ideally, I would like to output a reference with a format like "8 vols, 1 index", "8 vols, 1 appendix " or "8 vols, 1 supplementary vol."

Comment: Help us to help you providing a _Minimal Working Example_ with _Bibliography_ (_MWEB_). (i.e a compilable minimal _LaTeX document_ with its respective `<bibliography>.bib`). This makes it easier to reproduce your situation and propose a solution.

Comment: A solution will depend on the style you use. Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Even though your question is fairly general you will make it easier for us to get started and make sure things work with your setup.

Answer (score 4):

You could redefine the format of volumes to print a literal unless its a numeral. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{mvbook1,
  author = {AuthorA},
  title = {Title 1},
  volumes = {8 vols\adddot, 1 supplementary vol\adddot},
  location = {Location},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = {2017}
}
@mvbook{mvbook2,
  author = {AuthorB},
  title = {Title 2},
  volumes = {7},
  location = {Location},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volumes}{%
  \ifnumeral{#1}
    {#1 \bibstring{volumes}}
    {#1}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course the use of `\adddot` makes things slightly less portable in the `.bib` file. In this case we can get away with literal `.`s and `\isdot` in the field format.

Comment: @moewe Is it better to use `\bibstring{volumes}` and `\bibstring{volume}` directly? Actually, feel free to edit my answer as you see fit.

Comment: Mhhh, I'm not sure what you mean. If you use that in the `.bib` file you will make things even less portable. I nice, but much more complicated solution would be to allow for a new field, but I'm not entirely sure how the input and output would work. It is impracticable to have a `index` and `suppvolume` field...

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something with how `\adddot` and `\bibstring` work in bib fields. I would have thought that `volumes={8 \bibstring{volumes}}` and `volumes={8 vols\adddot}` were equivalent, since the `volumes` string is defined as `vols\adddot`. Or is this incorrect?

Comment: If you load `biblatex`, more or less (actually much more than less) yes. But if you use the same `.bib` file with `natbib`, the commands `\adddot` and `\bibstring{volumes}` are not defined, so will throw an error if used.

Comment: Ah, I see where you're coming from. Thanks.